# Achieving Custom Day View in Android

Tags: android, listview, events, android-recyclerview, kotlin

[image]

Hi everyone, I'm try to make a custom day view in application, similar to the Google Calender's day view.

There are two things that I need to figure out:

1. How to display an event on top of a ListView similiar to event of
   the 'Laliga match' in the reference image.
2. How to create events through selecting hours on the list, should I
   use buttons, checkboxes or what?

I'm kinda stuck here, any help would be appreciated! Thanks.